# Webform submitted data in views

Tags: 7

I am using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and displaying it using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Unfortunately, I couldn't get the submitted data of the webform in views.

Any suggeestions?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add new view 'admin/structure/views/add' and into Show select webform submission continue and edit ... you can get all the submission list into the view.

[image]

Add field webform submission data:value

[image]

Then select webform node and field you want.

[image]

You can see the fields like this

[image]

View result

[image]

Try it.

Comment: Thanks. How to do in drupal 8? Not seeing submission data field in drupal 8 view which is based on table webform submission.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view for your submissions, for example, lets create a table.

Add a new field, and look for "webform submission data: value". Once you have selected that, you will need to enter the name, or the nid of your webform, and then select a field to show that value.

If you cant see the "webform submission data: value" field right away, you may need to add a relationship to your view for that specific webform.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view by selecting webform submissions data and rendered submissions instead of fields under Display format.
Or follow the process from this : - [how-display-webform-submissions-views-drupal-7](http://www.ultechspot.com/drupal/how-display-webform-submissions-views-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are more complex, you may use [Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) and/or [Webform MySQL Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) modules.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, you need to install the "Webform Views" module to have the webform submission data show up in "Views".